# Effects of "No One of Consequence" on the rest of the adventuring party

Tags: pathfinder-1e, mythic-adventures

In Pathfinder Mythic Adventures there is a path ability under the Trickster Path that is giving me a bit of a hard time ruling as a GM:

> No One of Consequence (Ex)
>
> Your mythic nature is a cloak that can shield you from the minds and
>   memories of others. Creatures struggle to recognize you, recall your
>   appearance, remember the nature of conversations they had with you,
>   and recount the actions you took when you were in their presence. If a
>   creature makes a deliberate attempt to recall details about time spent
>   with you, it must succeed at a Will save (DC 10 + your tier + your
>   Charisma modifier) to recall anything beyond vague details. In
>   addition, you're under a permanent nondetection effect with a caster
>   level equal to your character level plus your tier. You can end this
>   effect at any time, and can resume it as a swift action.

My issue is interaction between the players. One of the players has taken this ability and I don't know how it interacts with the rest of the party. Do they recognize him? Do they remember him and their past experiences with him? Can he selectively affect people with it?

Furthermore, the Will Save for recalling information regarding him doesn't specify a time of effect. Say, if NPC 1 fails the Will Save, can he attempt to recall information again for a different Will Save? If he can, after what time window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing that requires an extraordinary ability to be always "on".

> Your mythic nature is a cloak that **can** shield you from the minds and memories of others.

"Can" means you are able to do this - it doesn't mean you *have* to. Just assume the character doesn't want this to affect his close acquaintances unless they want it to. If in doubt, ask.

Comment: Or more likely to “You can end this effect at any time, and can resume it as a swift action.”

Comment: Concur with @SevenSidedDie--if you can selectively end the effect, then it's only logical that your team-mates have been around you when the effect was off. They'll remember you--if they didn't, that would make dividing treasure really inconvenient.

Comment: @JustinEiler not inconvenient: lucrative. "Don't you remember? You got first choice last time, it's my turn."

Comment: How does it affect an NPC trying to remember? If he fails a saving throw will he get another one? If so, when?